# How to get top 2 records based on a week end date for each user for each week in a single row using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a user activity table on which we are capturing user login date.
Whenever the user logged in one entry recorded for that user along with his/her email id, access date and some other information.

Now I need to calculate status of that user at the end of each week which is Friday for last 52 weeks.
I
 have created one query to find out last 52 weeks Friday date or `end_of_week_date`.

I wanted to pass that date one by one for each user to get his first access date which is less than or equal to `end_of_week_date` and second access date which Should be less than first access date.

So as I have 16k users then I want first access date and second access date for each user for all 52 weeks.

I wanted to run all this together at the end of each week so i that i can get only last 52 weeks snapshot for each user.

Last 52 weeks Friday date query.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATE, a.Date_PK) as Week_End_Date, 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.weekno = 2 then  'Week 1' 
        WHEN a.weekno = 3 then  'Week 2' 
        WHEN a.weekno=4 then  'Week 3' 
        WHEN a.weekno=5 then  'Week 4' 
        WHEN a.weekno=6 then  'Week 5' 
        WHEN a.weekno=7 then  'Week 6' 
        WHEN a.weekno=8 then  'Week 7' 
        WHEN a.weekno=9 then  'Week 8' 
        WHEN a.weekno=10 then 'Week 9' 
        WHEN a.weekno=11 then 'Week 10'
        WHEN a.weekno=12 then 'Week 11'
        WHEN a.weekno=13 then 'Week 12'
        WHEN a.weekno=14 then 'Week 13'
        WHEN a.weekno=15 then 'Week 14'
        WHEN a.weekno=16 then 'Week 15'
        WHEN a.weekno=17 then 'Week 16'
        WHEN a.weekno=18 then 'Week 17'
        WHEN a.weekno=19 then 'Week 18'
        WHEN a.weekno=20 then 'Week 19'
        WHEN a.weekno=21 then 'Week 20'
        WHEN a.weekno=22 then 'Week 21'
        WHEN a.weekno=23 then 'Week 22'
        WHEN a.weekno=24 then 'Week 23'
        WHEN a.weekno=25 then 'Week 24'
        WHEN a.weekno=26 then 'Week 25'
        WHEN a.weekno=27 then 'Week 26'
        WHEN a.weekno=28 then 'Week 27'
        WHEN a.weekno=29 then 'Week 28'
        WHEN a.weekno=30 then 'Week 29'
        WHEN a.weekno=31 then 'Week 30'
        WHEN a.weekno=32 then 'Week 31'
        WHEN a.weekno=33 then 'Week 32'
        WHEN a.weekno=34 then 'Week 33'
        WHEN a.weekno=35 then 'Week 34'
        WHEN a.weekno=36 then 'Week 35'
        WHEN a.weekno=37 then 'Week 36'
        WHEN a.weekno=38 then 'Week 37'
        WHEN a.weekno=39 then 'Week 38'
        WHEN a.weekno=40 then 'Week 39'
        WHEN a.weekno=41 then 'Week 40'
        WHEN a.weekno=42 then 'Week 41'
        WHEN a.weekno=43 then 'Week 42'
        WHEN a.weekno=44 then 'Week 43'
        WHEN a.weekno=45 then 'Week 44'
        WHEN a.weekno=46 then 'Week 45'
        WHEN a.weekno=47 then 'Week 46'
        WHEN a.weekno=48 then 'Week 47'
        WHEN a.weekno=49 then 'Week 48'
        WHEN a.weekno=50 then 'Week 49'
        WHEN a.weekno=51 then 'Week 50'
        WHEN a.weekno=52 then 'Week 51'
        WHEN a.weekno=53 then 'Week 52'
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS Week_No 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         DATEPART(week, Date_pk) AS week,
         Date_PK,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_pk DESC) AS weekno
     FROM  
         dbo.Dim_Date
     WHERE  
         Date_PK BETWEEN DATEADD(Week, -53, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
         AND DATENAME(dw, Date_pk) = 'Friday') a
WHERE 
    a.weekno NOT IN (1)
ORDER BY 
    Week_End_Date DESC
```

Sample data is like this:

```
Emai           First_Name     AccessDate
-----------------------------------------
USER1@GMAIL      ABC          14-02-2019
USER1@GMAIL      ABC          12-02-2019
USER1@GMAIL      ABC          06-02-2019
USER1@GMAIL      ABC          01-02-2019
USER2@GMAIL      CDE          11-01-2019
USER2@GMAIL      CDE          10-02-2019
USER2@GMAIL      CDE          02-02-2019
USER2@GMAIL      CDE          27-01-2019
USER3@GMAIL      EFG          13-02-2019
USER3@GMAIL      EFG          11-02-2019
USER3@GMAIL      EFG          08-02-2019
USER3@GMAIL      EFG          07-02-2019
```

The result would be something like below

```
USER_Email   FIRST_ACCESS_DATE  SECOND_ACCESS_DATE  WEEK_NUMBER    WEEK_END_DATE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USER1@GMAIL      14-02-2019       12-02-2019           WEEK 1       15-02-2019
USER1@GMAIL      06-02-2019       01-02-2019           WEEK 2       08-02-2019
USER2@GMAIL      11-01-2019       10-02-2019           WEEK 1       15-02-2019
USER2@GMAIL      02-02-2019       27-01-2019           WEEK 2       08-02-2019
USER3@GMAIL      13-02-2019       11-02-2019           WEEK 1       15-02-2019
USER3@GMAIL      08-02-2019       07-02-2019           WEEK 2       08-02-2019
USER4@GMAIL      12-02-2019       09-02-2019           WEEK 1       15-02-2019
USER4@GMAIL      07-02-2019       01-02-2019           WEEK 2       08-02-2019
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I didn't understood why putting `First_Access_date` and `Second_access_Date` on different columns, and what if there are more access during the same week.*

```
--Create Table
CREATE TABLE #TBL(

Email varchar(50),
First_Name varchar(50),
AccessDate DateTime

)

--Insert Values
INSERT INTO #TBL(Email  ,         First_Name  ,   AccessDate)
VALUES
('USER1@GMAIL','ABC','20190214'),
('USER1@GMAIL','ABC','20190212'),
('USER1@GMAIL','ABC','20190206'),
('USER1@GMAIL','ABC','20190201'),
('USER2@GMAIL','CDE','20190111'),
('USER2@GMAIL','CDE','20190210'),
('USER2@GMAIL','CDE','20190202'),
('USER2@GMAIL','CDE','20190127'),
('USER3@GMAIL','EFG','20190213'),
('USER3@GMAIL','EFG','20190211'),
('USER3@GMAIL','EFG','20190208'),
('USER3@GMAIL','EFG','20190207')


--Get User Log info for last 52 week
SELECT Email USER_MAIL,  
       AccessDate ACCESS_DATE, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY DATEPART(WW,AccessDate) DESC) WEEK_NUMBER, 
       DATEADD(wk, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 0-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AccessDate), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, AccessDate))) WEEK_END_DATE
FROM #TBL
WHERE DATEDIFF(WW,AccessDate,GETDATE()) >= 0 AND 
      DATEDIFF(WW,AccessDate,GETDATE()) <= 52
ORDER BY Email,WEEK_NUMBER,AccessDate
```

**Result**

[image]

If you want only two top rows from each week:

```
WITH CTE_1 AS ( SELECT Email USER_MAIL,  
           AccessDate ACCESS_DATE, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY DATEPART(WW,AccessDate) DESC) WEEK_NUMBER, 
           DATEADD(wk, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 0-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AccessDate), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, AccessDate))) WEEK_END_DATE
    FROM #TBL
    WHERE DATEDIFF(WW,AccessDate,GETDATE()) >= 0 AND 
          DATEDIFF(WW,AccessDate,GETDATE()) <= 52
    ) ,CTE_2 AS (SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USER_MAIL,WEEK_NUMBER ORDER BY ACCESS_DATE DESC) as ACCESS_ORDER  FROM CTE_1 )
    SELECT * FROM CTE_2 WHERE ACCESS_ORDER <= 2 ORDER BY     USER_MAIL,WEEK_NUMBER,ACCESS_ORDER
```

**Result**

[image]

If you want to show first and second value.

```
WITH CTE_1 AS ( SELECT Email USER_MAIL,  
           AccessDate ACCESS_DATE, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY DATEPART(WW,AccessDate) DESC) WEEK_NUMBER, 
           DATEADD(wk, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 0-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AccessDate), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, AccessDate))) WEEK_END_DATE
    FROM #TBL
    WHERE DATEDIFF(WW,AccessDate,GETDATE()) >= 0 AND 
          DATEDIFF(WW,AccessDate,GETDATE()) <= 52
    ) ,CTE_2 AS (SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USER_MAIL,WEEK_NUMBER ORDER BY ACCESS_DATE DESC) as ACCESS_ORDER  FROM CTE_1 )
    SELECT DISTINCT USER_MAIL,  MIN(ACCESS_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_MAIL, WEEK_NUMBER) FIRST_ACCESS_DATE, MAX(ACCESS_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_MAIL, WEEK_NUMBER) SECOND_ACCESS_DATE, WEEK_NUMBER, WEEK_END_DATE FROM CTE_2 WHERE ACCESS_ORDER <= 2 ORDER BY      USER_MAIL,WEEK_NUMBER
```

- [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7c8cea404a9e125c0cc55f5f62b2278)

**References**

- [How to Get First and Last Day of a Week in SQL Server](http://zarez.net/?p=2543)

Comment: You could achieve the exact OP expected result by using aggregation on the last query , like `MAX(ACCESS_DATE), MIN(ACCESS_DATE)` (with more than two positions to display you would need conditional aggregation though).

Comment: @GMB thanks for the remarks. It can be achieve using min an max window function. I have the query but i didn't post it since i think it is not the right way

Comment: @GMB i added the query.

Comment: Yep, looks good now. Feel free to add this [db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7c8cea404a9e125c0cc55f5f62b2278) !

Comment: Thanks Marc for all your help.